# Generic interface inheritance (design issue)

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, new-operator

I have two interfaces; `ISet` and `ISet<T>`

Both implement Add, Remove and Clear but with different argument types; object and T.

Now I have two options. Either let `ISet<T>` inherit from `ISet`, or let them be isolated from each other.

One great benefit of having `ISet<T>` inherit from `ISet` is of course that I always can use a `ISet<T>` where-ever I need a `ISet`. But doing so I also have to add the "new" modifier to the members with a T-parameter. I don't like the "new"-modifier very much, but maybee this is the better option in this case?

It feels odd having a `ISet<T>` that isn't also a `ISet`. That's the logical assumption. I can't really say excatly why I don't like the "new"-modifier. It's like with the "goto"-keyword. I just try not to use it.

What do you think I should go with here? Inherit or not?

---

In .NET we have `ICollection<T>` and `ICollection` which doesn't inherit. Neither do `IList<T>` and `IList`. But `IEnumerable<T>` inherit from `IEnumerable`.

---

I know about the ISet-interface that allready exist (This was just an example)

Comment: You say the implement same Add, Remove, Clear... but what are the different "T"ypes you are trying to use as parameters.  How are they different, and how many different types (for example).

Comment: The non-generic versions of collection types are more or less deprecated in .NET; are you sure you really need the non-generic ISet interface? You can always use ISet<object> if you need a set that can hold any object. BTW there is already a generic [ISet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) interface in .NET.

Comment: If ISet/ISet<T> is just an example, you should give more details on your actual interfaces. If you're designing collection types, you've already found out how the .NET framework solves it for its collection types. (IEnumerable<T> extending IEnumerable is for historical reasons.) If you're not designing collection types, the situation may be completely different; you can find many examples in the .NET framework where a generic type extends a non-generic type of the same name.

Comment: If `ISet<T>` inherits `ISet`, what would you like to happen when I take an `ISet<Giraffe>`, cast it to `ISet`, and add a `new Rhinoceros()` to it?

Comment: AakashM: It would like it to crash.

Comment: dtb: I need the non-generic version to hold any kind of set-instance and also let me enumerate and work with content without knowing the specific content-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that inheriting from the non-generic form would really buy you is the ability to perform certain operations on an `ISet<T>` without having to know at compile time what the `T` was.  One couldn't add items to such a set in type-safe manner, and reading might be somewhat inefficient (since value types would have to be boxed), but methods or properties like `Count` could be perfectly useful.

My suggestion would be that you define multiple interfaces something like this (note that I'm adding some members that you don't have, since your collection is at moment write-only and thus not very useful)

```
interface ICountable { int Count {get;} }
interface IClearable { int Count {get;} }
interface IAppendable<in T> { void Add(T item); }
interface ICountableEnumerable<out T> : IConvertableToEnumerable, ICountable 
  {IEnumerable<T> CopyAsEnumerable();}
interface IFetchable<out T> { T FetchAndRemove(ref bool wasNonEmpty); }
interface ISet<T> ICountable, IClearable, IAppendable<T>, IFetchable<T>,
          IConvertableToEnumerable<T>;
```

Such interface segregation makes it possible to use covariance and contravariance to the extent that it makes sense.

Comment: Many interfaces yes, but I like the idea om using covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this problem in other situations as well. I usually resolve it by having `ISet<T>` have its versions of the methods, and `ISet` have its own excepting object. Just as you have mentioned. In addition to this I also create an abstract class called `BaseSet<T>` that implements both `ISet<T>` and `ISet` like so

```
public abstract class BaseSet<T> : ISet<T>, ISet {
  public abstract void Add<T>(T item);

  void ISet.Add(object item) {
     this.Add((T)item);
  } 
}
```

Then one only has to inherit from `BaseSet<T>` and implement the `ISet<T>` interface for the most common scenario, yet they can still fully implement `ISet<T>` and `ISet` if the `BaseSet<T>` convenience class does not fit what they need. It also removes the need for usage of the `new` keyword.

Comment: I like the use of declarative interface implementations to hide the overrides.

Comment: If you do this, you might want to match `List<T>`'s implementation of `IList`: List.Add(object) throws an exception if the type isn't correct, this implementation will add a null.

Comment: @DavidYaw - I agree. This was not a full implementation, just showing how to organize the classes. I updated to use an explicit cast operator, which would force the exception.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best to follow the general .NET paradim, but you could always look at doing it the other way around?

```
interface ISet : ISet<object>
{ }

interface ISet<T>
{
    void Add<T>(T item);
    void Clear();
    void Remove<T>(T item);
}
```

If it's a collection you're implementing is there an [alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) one in .NET you can use?

Comment: Nah that didn't work. I need ISet<T> to be a ISet, not the other way around. I need a common ground.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use ISet and provide Object as T if you want to use it with any Type?

Answer (score 0):

I think if your problem domain calls for a generic, deriving from the non generic doesn't necessarily buy you anything. Are there potential side effects from allowing objects in your typesafe version? If so, seems to me that was at least party of the problem generics were designed to overcome...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a non-generic `ISet`? .NET supports generics, there's little reason not to use them. I believe all .NET languages have full support for generics.

Yes, the .NET Library has both `IList` and `IList<T>`. However, I believe the reason for that is historical, from before .NET had generics. If generic support had been implemented from the beginning, I think `IList` wouldn't exist, only `IList<T>` would.

Comment: If I don't have a non-generic ISet I would never be able to work with sets in general without taking account to the actual type of the content. And I can't use "out T" because I have both output (enumeration) and input with Add(T item).

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple reason, why `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`. It's name is [foreach statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which works only with collection types. Any collection type should implement non-generic interface `IEnumerable` (even arrays implement it). Here is what happens behind foreach scene:

```
E enumerator = (collection).GetEnumerator(); // non-generic interface
try {
   while (enumerator.MoveNext()) { // enumerator also non-generic
      ElementType element = (ElementType)enumerator.Current;
      statement;
   }
}
finally {
   IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
   if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

So we have generic interfaces which inherit from non-generic to allow usage of generic collections within foreach statement. Other option was to change compiler :)

There no core .net features, which depend on `IList` interface. So, we have two independent interfaces - generic and non-generic.

In your case I don't see any reason for creating non-generic interface `ISet`. If you want to have a method, which accepts generic `ISet<T>` with different type parameters, then just create generic method, which accepts generic `ISet<T>`:

```
public void Foo<T>(ISet<T> set)
{
    set.Bar();
}
```